# How safe is firejail?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to execute untrusted C, C++, Python, Java and PHP program inside of a sandbox in ubuntu server. I don't know much about accessing host computer through hypervisor, or how firejail actually works and how safe it is. Can I sleep peacefully leaving my server to firejail?

Answer (score 1):

There are cases of [container breakout](https://blog.docker.com/2014/06/docker-container-breakout-proof-of-concept-exploit/) (as containers utilize the same namespace functionality as firejail).  How untrusted are you talking? Is this 'experimenting with well known public tools' or 'letting explicitly malicious users run free'?  It may help with the former and is probably not strong enough for the latter.

Comment: Well, the second one. Anybody can execute anything. I'm just trying not to let them interfere with the host OS, no filesystem access, no network access. Only compile and calculate.

Comment: That scenario sounds like this should be a host dedicated to that purpose, with an external firewall preventing it from making any outbound connections.